# Interacting with roads using maps in OSMDroid?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm trying to learn how to use OSMDroid on Android. I have come to the point were I have the MapView displaying maptiles from a zip archive on the SD-card. The archive was created with [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/) in the OpenStreetMap Mapnik format.

So I'm wondering how to interact with the roads and paths that are displayed on the map? I need to to this in order to calculate routes as far as I understand.

Is it possible at all using OSMDroid? Do I need to use a different map format?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "Mapnik format", you are using images. You need vector data to be able to use roads and paths. So you need to download or use a service to get the XML vector data from OpenStreetMap and then read in the XML to Java objects.

Comment: Can I still use OSMDroid to render the xml data to a map?